# Can I generate images with Next.js static site generation

Tags: next.js

I'm creating my blog with Next.js static site generation.

I write articles as markdown files and the Markdown component receives each file by `getStaticPaths` returning a list of markdown files.

I'd like to generate OGP images from markdown too with ImageMagick.

Can I export images with Next.js like `getStaticPaths`?

Comment: Hi, can you add some parts of your code?

Comment: Why hasn't loading the URL and using ImageMagick to generate it worked thus far?

Comment: I'd like to deploy my website with only static files because it's easy to deploy and migrate to other servers.